# Adobe AIR - RTMFP error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, multiplayer, rtmfp

We develop local multiplayer games in AIR+AS3+Flex environment. We use the p2plocal library, which based on the RTMFP protocol. We found the following error at the testing:
it seems there is a limit of the nodes numbers. Around about 16 nodes, errors appear in the RTMFP network. For example: if there are 15 nodes in the network already, and a new one joined to it, some older node dont see the new one and "vica versa". Over 16 nodes, the RTMFP newtwork is inaccurate: some nodes dont see some others without any logic.

Is this a problem of the RTMFP? Or maybe a Windows socket limit? Or..?

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

RTMFP is UDP based for P2P communication and is highly dependant on network (may not work reliably).

Test your RTMFP capabilities with these tools:
http://cc.rtmfp.net/
http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/07/rtmfp-connection-tester/

To develop a solution that works reliably for most users, a RTMP relay server can be used.